# How to iterate over a nested array hash structure in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I would like to store multiple configuration entries (which can be flexibly extended) in a data structure, something like this:

```
(def config [{:host "test", :port 1},{:host "testtest", :port 2}])
```

Later on I would like to iterate over and process each hash in that array.

Could somebody point out how to do that in Clojure?

Comment: Note, for purposes of clear communication, that `config` is a *vector* of *maps*.  A hash generally refers to the number resulting from a hash function.

Comment: Meh. Hash and map are both used, because either one can be unclear depending on context: sometimes a hash is related to hash-codes, and sometimes map is a function for transforming each element of a sequence. I think map is a more popular "default", but hash is in no way incorrect here.

Comment: In my experience people rarely (if every) use the term _hash_ on its own to refer a _map_. People use _hash table_ and _hash map_ regularly, but just _hash_ on its own doesn't sound like a data structure. This is made more confusing in this example because typically persistent maps in Clojure with 16 or fewer keys are stored in an _array map_, which is nothing like a _hash map/table_. Vectors are also definitely not the same as an array. We all understand what the poster meant after reading the sample code, but it's good to use the right terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `for` (or `doseq` if you only want side-effects) to loop over each map stored in the vector. You can even use [destructuring](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html) to bind the individual keys of the map if you know them in advance:

```
(def config [{:host "test", :port 1},{:host "testtest", :port 2}])

(for [{h :host p :port} config]
  (format "host: %s ; port: %s" h p))

; => ("host: test ; port: 1" "host: testtest ; port: 2")
```

Answer (score 3):

One convenient way could be to use map

```
 (map #(print (:host %1)) config)
```

Or just in general

```
 (map my-processing-func config)
```